# App revenue after development account expired?

Tags: ios, app-store

Just wondering, I have a developer account for one year and I published a app on app store.
but after one year, the account expired and my app still making money by download or AD, can I still get the revenue? and the app will still online until apple make any policy changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html)

> What happens if I do not renew my iOS Developer Program membership?
>
> If you do not renew your iOS Developer Program membership, you will
>   retain your status as an Apple Developer and will have access to free
>   development resources, but you will lose your ability to distribute
>   applications on the App Store and your access to the iOS Provisioning
>   Portal. In addition, your existing Development and Distribution
>   certificates and provisioning profiles will be revoked and
>   invalidated. You will also lose access to pre-release software,
>   available discussion forums, and Developer Technical Support.

From what I understand from this, Your app is as good as removed from the app store..:(